# List all the Community Members in PHP with MySQL Query

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop

i want to list all the members of my website, in my index page, but i dont know how to do, i tried with while loop but it turns into infinite loop because i just tell it to while its smaller than integer exc..

Here is my code :

```
<?php
$profile_query = "SELECT * FROM `members` ORDER BY `join_date` DESC";
$profile_query_check = $db->prepare($profile_query);
$profile_query_check->execute();
$ac = $db->query("SELECT FOUND_ROWS()")->fetchColumn();
if(!empty($ac)) {
$_loader = true;
$fetch = $profile_query_check->fetch (PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$profile_name = $fetch['profile_name'];
$profile_photo = $fetch['profile_photo'];
$profile_id = $fetch['profile_id'];

while($profile_id <1000) { // this is the place i want to change to make it working well :)
?> 
<li><a href="http://mywebsite.com/profiles/<?php echo $profile_id;?>">  
<img src="http://mywebsite.com/photos/<?php echo $profile_photo;?>" />
<br>  
<?php echo $profile_name; ?></a></li>  
<?php } ?>
```

As i said, its printing well, but page goes mad and the infinite loop starts, and my browser gets crazy :)
Is there any mysql or php function that i can apply here that fetch all the rows and where it stops, stop the printing or something like that

Thank you for your advices.

Regards

Edit : Michael fixed the error, but this time its showing all the profiles except the last one, how can i fix that too ?

Comment: What do you need `SELECT FOUND_ROWS()` for?

Comment: Dude, your while loop has nothing in it to update the `$profile_id` so it will ALWAYS be less that 1000, so infinite loop.

Comment: i know thats the reason but how can i fix that

Comment: @Castiel Martin: you need to `fetch` the data in the loop, not out of it

Comment: thank you zerkms for you idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should change it to be something like this:

```
while ($fetch = $profile_query_check->fetch (PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    if ($fetch == NULL OR $fetch["profile_id"] > 1000) {
        break;
    }


    $profile_name = $fetch['profile_name'];
    $profile_photo = $fetch['profile_photo'];
    $profile_id = $fetch['profile_id'];

    //echo the profile info
}
```

Otherwise, the way you are doing it now, you are only fetching one row from the returned data, so that profile_id will always be < 1000 (unless the first returned is greater than 1000)

Comment: that fixed the infinite loop and printing the total profiles number, but always printing the same profile, imo as @zerkms mentioned above, i should fetch the data in the loop ?

Comment: Yes, that is the idea. I have edited my answer to include that.

Comment: oh sorry for asking again but it doesnt show the latest member, showing all except the last one, how can i fix that ?

Comment: @CastielMartin That sounds like either a different problem or the new member has an Id of over 1000